# UIWeb view load data prior view is loaded on the tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app which has 3 tab bar controller in which 3rd tab bar loads a url in UIWebView. I want to load web view data prior users click on 3rd tab bar. As now when i click on 3rd tab bar it load WebView data and then shows up on screen.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Have you tried creating a function in your 3rd view controller that loads the webview page and calling it right before you set the tab bars view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `UITabBarController` and implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
@interface MyTabBarController () <UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    ...
}

@implementation MyTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyThirdViewController class]]) {
        // Set url and load it
    }
}

@end
```